# LocalPushNotification in iphone

Tags: iphone

When iPhone application go to applicationWillResignActive mode, I need to download the data from specific site continuously(Using Timer) and if any data receive from that site should push the UILocalNotification. But if App has enter into Background, Downloading functions is not calling. Exactly i want as Mail app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that unless you're a VoIP app or a GPS app.

For other types of app, the closest you can do is request the 10 minute long task completion mode. That'll give you ten minutes of running whatever you want in the background, after which the system kills your app.